# pcolormesh in polar coordinates - redux

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

So I cannot get a polar surface plot of this doppler map. Here's the setup:

```
phis = np.linspace(0.0001,50,51) 
thetas = np.linspace(0,360,721)

doppMap = \
    np.array([[doppler(i * deg, j * deg).value for i in thetas] for j in phis]) * units.kHz
```

So I now have a 2D array of doppler values going from 0-360 in theta, and from 0-50 in phi ... If I plot this in cartesian coordinates it looks like what I expect:

[image]

This works with two different calls to `pcolomesh`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(thetas, phis)  # Create a grid over the range of bins for the plot
im = (ax.pcolormesh(thetas, phis, doppMap, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, alpha=0.95,shading='auto',edgecolors='face') )
## or
im = (ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, doppMap, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, alpha=0.95,shading='auto',edgecolors='face') )


ax.set_xlabel("theta [$\degree$]",fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("phi [$\degree$]",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xticks([x*30 for x in range(360//30)])
ax.grid(True)

plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
## Add colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.15, 0.015, 0.7])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14) 
#cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['1', '2', '4', '6', '10', maxCV], size=24)
#cbar.set_label(r"log ($P(\overline{Z_{G}} /Z_{\odot})$ / $d(M_{G}/M_{\odot})$)",fontsize=36)
cbar.set_label(r"$d$f [kHz]",fontsize=24)

gc.collect()
```

However, when I try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(thetas,phis)  # Create a grid over the range of bins for the plot

im = (ax.pcolormesh(thetas,phis, doppMap, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, alpha=0.95,shading='auto',edgecolors='face') )
## or
im = (ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, doppMap, cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, alpha=0.95,shading='auto',edgecolors='face') )


ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)

plt.thetagrids([theta * 15 for theta in range(360//15)])
ax.grid(True)

plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
## Add colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.15, 0.015, 0.7])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14) 
#cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['1', '2', '4', '6', '10', maxCV], size=24)
#cbar.set_label(r"log ($P(\overline{Z_{G}} /Z_{\odot})$ / $d(M_{G}/M_{\odot})$)",fontsize=36)
cbar.set_label(r"$d$f [kHz]",fontsize=24)

gc.collect()
```

I see this (which is completely wrong):
[image]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out... the outer axis is in radians!

```
phis2   = np.linspace(0.001,50,201) 
thetas2 = np.linspace(0,2.01*np.pi,201)

print(phis2.shape,thetas2.shape)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(thetas2,phis2)
doppMap2 =doppler(X*units.rad,Y*deg)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,7),subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

im=ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,doppMap2,cmap=mpl.cm.jet_r, edgecolors='face')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)

# ax.set_xticks([x*30 for x in range(360//30)])
ax.grid(True)

plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
## Add colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.15, 0.015, 0.7])
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=14) 
#cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['1', '2', '4', '6', '10', maxCV], size=24)
#cbar.set_label(r"log ($P(\overline{Z_{G}} /Z_{\odot})$ / $d(M_{G}/M_{\odot})$)",fontsize=36)
cbar.set_label(r"$d$f [kHz]",fontsize=24)
```

Results in

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this information it was helpful. One comment is that it would be helpful if you added some context on why the new code worked. The answer is that the outer axis must be in units of radians for the polar projection to work.